# How to pass variable in feature background "Given" statement in cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, jgiven

```
@TestHomeValidation
Feature:copy function test

  Background:
    Given I am running test in "VARIABLE" environment
```

Can I use `VARIABLE` in above background given statement? I want to pass this VARIABLE value from properties file.

Comment: It's just great how some questions are being downvoted without any reason provided.

Comment: indeed this is quite a nice question actually

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with [QAF gherkin client](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html).

```
@TestHomeValidation
Feature:copy function test

  Background:
    Given I am running test in "${my.env}" environment
```

Provide your `my.env` in property file. Further more you can have [environment specific resources](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/managing_resources_for_different_env.html) that you can configure with QAF

Answer (score 1):

I afraid you want be able to use external data source for storing variables to provide to Cucumber steps. What you might consider us using `DataTable`s `Scenario Outline`s. In both cases you can provide some local(intra-feature file) parameters. For example:

```
Scenario: Scenario1 
  Given I have done "this" #this can be parsed by the glue code
  Then these can be used: #You can use DataTable type to parse multiple groups of variables
    | col1 | col2 | col3 |
    | x    | x1   | x2   |
    | y    | y1   | y2   |


Scenario Outline: <col1> test 
  Given I have done "<col2>"
  Then I can see "<col3>"
    | col1 | col2 | col3 |
    | par1 | par2 | par3 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @eugene-s mentioned this is not possible out of the box.

I have a similar case where I need to substitute and possible add more variables from external file.

The solution we going for is to parse the features with [Gherkin parser](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/gherkin), put in the values and create new tree which can be either written to a new file and passed along or substituted directly in the test runner.

if interested you can follow the development [here](https://github.com/apptik/tarator/issues/1)